# EF double slash parameter in query variable not giving any results

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a query that contains a string that looks like this: .
When I put this into my query hardcoded it does return results and as a variable it doesn't.

```
var myresult = RepositoryQuery.Where(a => a.Account== @"domain\\user");
```

Works.

```
string account= "domain\\user";
var user = RepositoryQuery.Where(a => a.Account == account);
```

Does not work.

```
Account GetAccount(account){
return RepositoryQuery.Where(a => a.Account == account);
}
```

Does not work.

```
Account GetAccount(account){
return RepositoryQuery.Where(a => a.Account == @account);
}
```

Does not work.

My guess is that it would have to do with the backslashes, but I can't any answers.

I found someone with the same [problem](http://forums.asp.net/t/1896790.aspx/1?Issue%20with%20Double%20slash%20Parameter) but I couldn't get a solution out of it.

What am I doing wrong?

[edit]

Updated the typo var name.

```
account.Replace("\\", "\\\\");
```

If I replace it like this it works. 
Looks ugly though..

[Solution]
So the account string I get from my session has already been escaped. I decided to replace the backslashes at session creation to keep the databases in line and not have one with double backslashes and one with single.

Comment: Try checking that SQL actually executes on the server. Perhaps there are some clues there..

Comment: Have you tried my corrected code?

Comment: You use wrong variable name in your linq select.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes you have to be aware of what you are looking at might have been changed by the IDE visually, when debugging, for example you could get confused when looking at filepaths in visual studio. where a string "`c:\something\file.bla"` could be shown as `"c:\\something\\file.bla"`
this also happens in connection strings and other things.

In your case `@"domain\\user"` is really `"domain\\user"`

whereas if you don't use the verbatim string 
`"domain\\user"` would be `"domain\user"` when querying the database.

Use:

```
string accountid = @"domain\user"
```

Or

```
string accountid = "domain\\user"
```

On a second note:
the @ in front of a variable is used to allow you to use reserved words as your variable names.
something like:

```
string @class = "1st. class";
```

Or

```
bool @if = true;
if(@if)
{
  Console.WriteLine("If is: "+ @if); //would print "If is: true"
}
```

Comment: Is there any way of getting the @"" effect on a variable string then?

Comment: You could do `accountid.Replace(@"\\",@"\")` if you wanted to make sure the backslaches were not double, but that doesnt mean that other escape characters couldnt sneak in, stuff like `"\r\n"` is a windows line ending for example, would probably be "invisible"

Answer (score 1):

Your first mistake: you filter with account variable instead of accountid.

Maybe it behaves as an escape character, try with verbatim string:

```
string accountid =  @"domain\\user";
```

or  if you store it with single backslash:

```
string accountid =  @"domain\user";
```

I think this could work:

```
string accountid = @"domain\user";
var user = RepositoryQuery.Where(a => a.Account == accountid );
```

or this (but I don't suggest):

```
string accountid = "domain\\user";
var user = RepositoryQuery.Where(a => a.Account == accountid );
```

Comment: Yes mybad, the @ before the string works. Just the string does not. 
@ before the variable does not work.

Comment: @speti43 +1. I think you are right. There is no magic going on (in this case), on the EF/SQL side

Comment: There was a mistake with the parameter name in the where clause. I've corrected it. You filtered with == account, but the correct is: == accountid

Comment: @WoutervanderHouven @ before a variable name lets you use a reserved keyword as identifier ("@for" is a valid identifier). @ before a string is used to declare a verbatim string (no escapes).